# Choosing Index on table

Tags: database-indexes, database-tuning

My table have 10 columns but i will use 5 columns more frequent.
which is the better way to create an index 
like do we have to create index in all the 5 columns or composite index do we have to create.
Actually performance is main thing to consider
i don't have much idea in tuning side.

Comment: Basically you should create indexes on column which are more used in your  WHERE, ORDER BY, and GROUP BY clauses, not based on your select columns.

Comment: I removed all the conflicting DBMS tags. Please add **only** the tag for the DBMS product you are really using? Indexing strategies will be different for different database products.

Comment: Okay thanks. a_horse_with_no_name

Comment: @PSK Yes i'm using those 5 columns in my where clause / some join conditions

Comment: @Explorerer This depends on how you reference your table in your queries exactly. It's impossible to say which indexes to create for such a vague description like `using those 5 columns in my where clause / some join conditions`. Some RDBMS have so called `index advisers` which can recommend you a set of indexes for some particular query and even for a set of queries.

Comment: Show us the queries; we can help you optimize the indexes.  Or use my Cookbook:  http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/index_cookbook_mysql  Throwing all 5 into a single composite index is _not_ likely to help much.